# Repopulate DAC on a daily schedule

Tags: acumatica

We want to truncate and repopulate a DAC on a daily scheduled basis. The dataset to repopulate is expected to be very large and going to be generated from SQL code in a customization project. Before we go down this route, we want to know if automated refresh of this would be possible.

Comment: Could you please share the code at least for some part of the data re-population part? This sounds like a standard use case of a processing pages with Automation Scheduler.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a DAC containing a list of DACs to Truncate/Repopulate.  Create a Process Page with the Primary View containing this DAC which will process the data in the way you describe for the specific DAC selected.  You can then set up an Automated Schedule with a filter criteria listing the particular DAC in your list.